# Remove the overlap line left by PostGIS ST_Difference

Tags: postgis, overlapping-features, st-difference

I need to remove any overlapping from these two polygons
[image: poliA and poliB]
when I run

```
select geometry(ST_Difference(poliA::geometry, poliB::geometry))
```

apparently returns A-B but, if I use  ST_Intersection to look for any overlapping area it's returning a line that matches with part of the border where both polygons collide.

```
select geometry (ST_Intersection( (select geometry(ST_Difference(poliA::geometry, poliB::geometry))),poliB::geometry)
```

[image: blue line is the overlap]

I even tried to remove it using Arcgis Pro altering the xy tolerance but can't get rid of overlapping lines and dots, and ST_Difference is not doing better

Comment: I'm thinking about using a negative buffer for the polygons and afterwards buffering them again with the same postive value again. Would that work?

Comment: I need to preserve the shape of polygon A

Answer (score 6):

This behaviour is expected. If two polygons are adjacent they [intersect](http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/spatial_relationships.html).

These four grid squares does not overlap, the result of their intersection can be a linestring:

```
select st_intersection(t1.geom, t2.geom)
from public.grid4 t1
join
public.grid4 t2
on st_intersects(t1.geom, t2.geom)
where t1.id=1 and t2.id=2
```

[image]
Or a point

[image]

Check if they overlap with st_overlaps, they dont:

```
select *
from public.grid4 t1
join
public.grid4 t2
on st_overlaps(t1.geom, t2.geom)
where t1.id=1 and t2.id=2
```

[image]

If you for some reason want to use intersects you can limit the result by st_area or st_dimension:

```
select  t1.id, 
        t2.id, 
        st_astext(st_intersection(t1.geom, t2.geom)), 
        st_area(st_intersection(t1.geom, t2.geom)), 
        st_dimension(st_intersection(t1.geom, t2.geom))
from newgrid t1
join newgrid t2
on st_intersects(t1.geom, t2.geom)
where t1.id < t2.id
--and st_area(st_intersection(t1.geom, t2.geom))>100
--and st_dimension(st_intersection(t1.geom, t2.geom))=2
```

[image]

Comment: st_overlaps returns true since there's the line I shown on the pic. what I'm trying to do is to get A without this line that overlaps with polygon B

Comment: If it is a line you can filter it by using st_dimension

Answer (score 2):

The only way I found to solve the problem was using the Reshape tool from Arcgis Pro (Edition module) to cut manually all the overlapping segments. Leaving this comment here in case somebody sees him/herself in this situation.